# Double selection combo box in Struts2

Tags: javascript, html, struts2

Below, I tried to see if the list contains two items

```
s:doubleselect label="doubleselect test1" name="menu" list="{'fruit','other'}" 
doubleName="dishes" doubleList="top == 'fruit' ? {'apple', 'orange'} : 
{'monkey', 'chicken'}"
```

If the list containts three or more items `{'fruit','flower','other'}` what should be syntax for `doubleList`?

Comment: If  there is any other tag to get this kind of functionality please let me know ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sdoubleselect-example/